# Get WebElements not getting executed in robotframework with java

Tags: java, robotframework, selenium2library

I am working on robotframework with java
There are several keywords which are working but then i have below Get Weblememts keyword, which is not getting executed when i see in report. And build is success

${all_Endpoints}=   Get WebElements   //div[contains(@class,'rt-tr table__row--medium')][@role='row']/div[2]/button[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg6PU.png)/span[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg6PU.png)

The above locator matches 11 webelements

Same behavior when i use Get List Items. I am using latest version of SeleniumLibrary and robot framework.Please help

```
My robot file is as below
*** Keywords ***
Go to Enterprise tab and verify software list
    Sleep    2s
    Click Link    ${lnk_enterpriseLink} 
    Page Should Contain    Select software
    Page Should Contain    Endpoints
    Sleep    2s
 Input Text      ${ent_software_dropdown}    APM
    Press Key    ${ent_software_dropdown}    \ue015
    Press Key    ${ent_software_dropdown}    \ue007
    Input Text    ${ent_software_env}   PRD
     Press Key    ${ent_software_env}    \ue015
    Press Key     ${ent_software_env}   \ue007
    Sleep    2s
${all_Endpoints}=   Get List Items  //div[contains(@class,'rt-tr table__row--medium')][@role='row']/div[2]/button[1]/span[1]
    Sleep    4s

And in POM i have below dependencies
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.hi-fi</groupId>
    <artifactId>robotframework-seleniumlibrary</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59.26535</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>com.sun</groupId>
    <artifactId>tools</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <scope>system</scope>
    <systemPath>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_221\lib\tools.jar</systemPath>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.robotframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>robotframework</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.2</version>
</dependency>

 <dependency>
      <groupId>org.python</groupId>
      <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.python</groupId>
      <artifactId>jython</artifactId>
      <version>2.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

and below is report
[Log Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fg6PU.png)

Comment: You provide very little information of you setup.  How do you run the test execution? With Jython? Better show the versions of the libraries, and also the log part that you say it does not execute. The best is to create a small but complete reproducible example we may try to run.

Comment: Hi Sir, I have added my POM, My robot file content and log file pic in question, as you see in report build is success but Get WebElements keyword is not getting executed at all

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should update SeleniumLibrary to be more in sync with RobotFramework version you use (4.1.2). But below change implies upgrading Java to version 11.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.github.marketsquare</groupId>
    <artifactId>robotframework-seleniumlibrary</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.0.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Read documentation at: https://github.com/MarketSquare/robotframework-seleniumlibrary-java

Comment: Hello Sir, I upgraded to Java 11 from Java 8 and have latest robotframework and SeleniumLibrary 4.0.0.0 as you suggested. Again I see success and in report Get WebElements keyword is not executed. Same issue

Comment: when i execute below keyword without giving variables to store webelemets, than it shows error :::                                                                                                                                                                            
                                                       Get WebElements //div[contains(@class,'rt-tr table__row--medium')][@role='row']/div[2]/button[1]/span[1]
Start / End / Elapsed: 20220101 20:41:22.670 / 20220101 20:41:22.693 / 00:00:00.023
20:41:22.672 FAIL No keyword with name 'Get WebElements' found.

Comment: Looking at Keywords Documentation, that keyword does not exist in this Java implementation. https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/github/marketsquare/robotframework-seleniumlibrary/4.0.0.0/robotframework-seleniumlibrary-4.0.0.0.html